# Trying to make inline divs with internal divs

Tags: html, css

I've got the following structure:

```css
.pinyined-char {
  display: inline-block;
}

.unpinyined-char {
  display: inline-block;
}

.pinyin {
  font-size: 10 px;
  text-align: center;
}

.char {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
  <div class="pinyined-char">
<div class="pinyin">duō</div>
<div class="char">多</div>
  </div>
  <div class="unpinyined-char">
<div class="pinyin"></div>
<div class="char">，</div>
  </div>
  <div class="pinyined-char">
<div class="pinyin">qǐng</div>
<div class="char">請</div>
  </div>
  <div class="pinyined-char">
<div class="pinyin">fǎng wèn</div>
<div class="char">訪問</div>
  </div>
  <div class="unpinyined-char">
<div class="pinyin"></div>
<div class="char"><a href="http://www.Caringo.com">http://www.Caringo.com</a> 。 
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="pinyined-char">
<div class="pinyin">àn zhào</div>
<div class="char">按照</div>
  </div>
  <div class="unpinyined-char">
<div class="pinyin"></div>
<div class="char">Caringo LinkedIn： https ： //<a href="http://www.linkedin.com/company/caringo-inc-">www.linkedin.com/company/caringo-inc-</a> Twitter： https ： //twitter.com/CaringoStorage 
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="pinyined-char">
<div class="pinyin">guān yú</div>
<div class="char">關於</div>
  </div>
  <div class="unpinyined-char">
<div class="pinyin"></div>
<div class="char">Caringo Caringo</div>
  </div>
  <div class="pinyined-char">
<div class="pinyin">shè bèi</div>
<div class="char">設備</div>
  </div>
  <div class="pinyined-char">
<div class="pinyin">hé</div>
<div class="char">咊</div>
  </div>
  <div class="unpinyined-char">
<div class="pinyin"></div>
<div class="char">Caringo LinkedIn</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ultimately, I want all of the .pinyined-char and .unpinyined-char .char divs to line up next to each other, with the .pinyin divs on top

I can sorta get this working by putting `display: inline-block` on .pinyined-char and .unpinyined-char, but I find that it doesn't wrap well

How do I make this wrap properly and put everything inline, while keeping pinyin on top of the respective characters in .char?

Example:

**NOTE: I have edited the example to be much closer to what I am experiencing.** The problem I am trying to solve is between the

```
àn zhào
按  照
```

line and the `Caringo Linkedin`. I would like that Caringo Linkedin to appear on the same line and wrap.

https://jsfiddle.net/70kbtLru/11/

Comment: Isn’t [`<ruby>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ruby) what you want?

Comment: ahhh... maybe. I am unaware of this specific element. I'll look into it. unpinyined-char is typically English text though. I'll clarify that.

Comment: Sounds like you need to use a table. You also have an extra </div> on line 3 that might be causing an issue.

Comment: @BryanJosephMyers - Yeah, that was a typo. I cleaned it up here and in the fiddle

Comment: And that isn't doing what you want?

Comment: No, the cleaned up version that I have is not doing what I want. It isn't wrapping well, as mentioned

Comment: Actually it doesn't appear like ruby is what I want - there's no way to mix ruby and non-asian language text, is there?

Comment: Do you want them horizontally aligned to the center?

Comment: Create a wrapper `div` to contain, use a `table` to position the english and other language, and use another `div` next to the `table` for the last text - or just use another table cell to hold that one, and increase the size accordingly.

Comment: Actually @Xufox - switching my structure to <ruby> and <span> instead of divs inside of container divs worked perfectly as now everything is by default inline elements. If you want to put that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is specifically what the HTML5 [`<ruby>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ruby) element was introduced for. In a `<ruby>` element you can add ruby annotations with the `<rt>` tag, while using `<rp>` for backwards compatibility.

Something like

```
duō
 多
```

can be rendered by this code:

```
<ruby>
多 <rp>(</rp><rt>duō</rt><rp>)</rp>
</ruby>
```

Browsers that [don’t support `<ruby>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ruby#Browser_compatibility) will render it like this, depending on the choice of `<rp>` parentheses:

```
多 (duō)
```

---

Taking your current example of annotated text, the HTML would look something like this:

```html
<ruby>
多 <rp>(</rp><rt>duō</rt><rp>)</rp>
</ruby>
，
<ruby>
請 <rp>(</rp><rt>qǐng</rt><rp>)</rp>
訪 <rp>(</rp><rt>fǎng</rt><rp>)</rp>
問 <rp>(</rp><rt>wèn</rt><rp>)</rp>
</ruby>
<a href="https://www.Caringo.com">https://www.Caringo.com</a> 。
<ruby>
按 <rp>(</rp><rt>àn</rt><rp>)</rp>
照 <rp>(</rp><rt>zhào</rt><rp>)</rp>
</ruby>
Caringo LinkedIn： <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/caringo-inc-">https://www.linkedin.com/company/caringo-inc-</a> Twitter： <a href="https://twitter.com/CaringoStorage">https://twitter.com/CaringoStorage</a>
<ruby>
關 <rp>(</rp><rt>guān</rt><rp>)</rp>
於 <rp>(</rp><rt>yú</rt><rp>)</rp>
</ruby>
Caringo Caringo
<ruby>
設 <rp>(</rp><rt>shè</rt><rp>)</rp>
備 <rp>(</rp><rt>bèi</rt><rp>)</rp>
咊 <rp>(</rp><rt>hé</rt><rp>)</rp>
</ruby>
Caringo LinkedIn
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```css
.pinyined-char, .unpinyined-char  {
    display: inline-block;
}
.pinyin {
    font-size: 10px;
}
.char, .pinyin {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="pinyined-char">
    <div class="pinyin">shè bèi</div>
    <div class="char">設備</div>
  </div>
  <div class="pinyined-char">
    <div class="pinyin">hé</div>
    <div class="char">咊</div>
  </div>
  <div class="unpinyined-char">
    <div class="pinyin"></div>
    <div class="char">Caringo LinkedIn</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="pinyined-char">
    <div class="pinyin">shè bèi</div>
    <div class="char">設備</div>
  </div>
  <div class="pinyined-char">
    <div class="pinyin">hé</div>
    <div class="char">咊</div>
  </div>
  <div class="unpinyined-char">
    <div class="pinyin"></div>
    <div class="char">Caringo LinkedIn</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Otherwise, here it is with a table.. and each word vertically aligned to each character.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>shè</td>
    <td>bèi</td>
    <td>hé</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>設</td>
    <td>備</td>
    <td>咊</td>
    <td>Caringo LinkedIn</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>shè</td>
    <td>bèi</td>
    <td>hé</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>設</td>
    <td>備</td>
    <td>咊</td>
    <td>Caringo LinkedIn</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Will this table structure work also with the non-chinese text?

Comment: Should work. Might make some changes if you want the "Caringo LinkedIn" text horizontally aligned with the word row. Or if you want it aligned middle vertically.

Answer (score 0):

This here was with the code exactly like you showed (ie, two different sets of texts / with matching translations)

This snippet can easily be extended to add more text in the table, if needed

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
td {
  text-align: center;
}

.char,span {
    text-align: center;
    align-self: flex-end;
    padding-bottom: .3em;
    padding-left: .5em;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>duō</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>多</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <span>,</span>
    <table>
    <tr>
      <td>qǐng</td>
      <td>fǎng wèn</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>請</td>
      <td>訪問</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="char">
    <a href="http://www.Caringo.com">http://www.Caringo.com</a>
    </div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>àn zhào</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>按照</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="char">
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/caringo-inc-">Caringo LinkedIn</a>
      <a href="https://twitter.com/CaringoStorage">Twitter</a>
    </div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>guān yú</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>關於</td>
  </tr>
</table>   
<div class="char">Caringo Caringo</div>
    <table>
    <tr>
      <td>shè bèi</td>
      <td>hé</td>
    </tr>
   <tr>

      <td>設備</td>
      <td>咊</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div class="char">Caringo LinkedIn</div>
</div>
```